# Php upload files dirrectly to gridFS in windows

Tags: php, apache, mongodb

I'm currently running on a Windows 7 box, with apache and PHP5,
tinkering around with MongoDB.

I was wondering if there's any way to have an application upload
files dirrectly into GridFS without ever creating a temp file.
I've read something about NginX being a good solution to this,
but not for windows.

Possible? Thoughts?
Thanks,
-JWW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, nginx and the [nginx upload module](http://www.grid.net.ru/nginx/upload.en.html) will generate a temp file. The upside to this is that instead of passing a presumably large file to a PHP process, you would only be passing the location for it, thus having PHP consume less memory in handling the upload.

Either with Apache or nginx, a temporary file will be created one way or another, I suppose. I guess you could just not send your form with a `multipart/form-data` content-type and try your best at parsing `fopen("php://input", "r");`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nuts, so it sounds like there's not an easy way to get around loading large file uploads into server ram (at least not by piping them into GridFs), right?

Comment: Why would you want to upload it into RAM? Having nginx handling the whole deal and then just telling GridFS to load it in will likely be a better choice